# How to copy folders with 'gsutil'?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I've read the documentation on the `gsutil cp` command, but still don't understand how to copy folders to keep the same permissions. I tried this command:

```
gsutil cp gs://bucket-name/folder1/folder_to_copy gs://bucket-name/folder1/new_folder
```

But it resulted with the error:

```
CommandException: No URLs matched
```

Although, when I tried it with slashes in the end of each name, it didn't show any error:

```
gsutil cp gs://bucket-name/folder1/folder_to_copy/ gs://bucket-name/folder1/new_folder/
```

However, there was no new folder in the bucket when I checked with `gsutil ls`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean with folder permission's ? You talking about ACLs ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### Using cp

You should use the [`-r`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#options) option to copy a folder and its contents recursively:

```
gsutil cp -r gs://bucket-name/folder1/folder_to_copy gs://bucket-name/folder1/new_folder
```

Note that this will only work if `folder_to_copy` contains files. This is due to the fact Cloud Storage doesn't really have "folders" as one would expect in a typical GUI, it instead provides the illusion of a hierarchical file tree atop the "flat" name space, as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork). In other words, the files within a folder are simply objects that have the folder prefix appended to them. Therefore, when you're doing `gsutil cp`, it expects actual objects to be copied and not empty directories which is something the CLI does not understand.

---

### Using rsync

Another approach would be to simply use [`rsync`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) instead, which tolerates  the use of empty folders and also synchronizes the contents between source and destination folders:

```
gsutil rsync -r gs://bucket-name/folder1/folder_to_copy gs://bucket-name/folder1/new_folder
```

If you also want to preserve the ACL (permissions) of the objects, use the [`-p`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync#options) option:

```
gsutil rsync -p -r gs://bucket-name/folder1/folder_to_copy gs://bucket-name/folder1/new_folder
```

Comment: @praytic - To add to this answer, which is correct, you can use wildcards `*`. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames

Comment: But I don't want to copy contents of the folder. I need to copy permissions of the folder and create a new one with the same permissions.

Comment: @Praytic Well, folders don't really exist in Cloud Storage as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming#object-considerations), so you can't assign permissions to them. You can give an ACL to individual objects though, and preserve it with the [`-p`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync#options) option when doing `gsutil rsync` or other `gsutil` commands.

Comment: Note that `gs://bucket-name/folder1/folder_to_copy` **should not contain a trailing slash** like `gs://bucket-name/folder1/folder_to_copy/`

Comment: There is now [`gcloud storage cp`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/storage/cp) which is ["fast by default"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTJGdoC2aVE).

Comment: Adding to the cp with the -r option, if you're copying a large amount of files I recommend using gsutil -m cp -r to perform multiple requests in parallel which results in a huge speedup.

Answer (score 11):

To add to @Maxim's answer, you might consider using the `-m` argument when calling `gsutil` to allow parallel copy.

```sh
gsutil -m cp -r gs://bucket-name/folder1/folder_to_copy gs://bucket-name/folder1/new_folder
```

The `-m` arg enables parallelism.

As advised in the `gsutil` doc, the `-m` arg might not yield better performance with a slow network (*i.e.*, at home). But for the case of inter bucket copy (machines in data center) the performance are likely to "significantly improve" to quote gsutil manual. See below

```
 -m          Causes supported operations (acl ch, acl set, cp, mv, rm, rsync,
              and setmeta) to run in parallel. This can significantly improve
              performance if you are performing operations on a large number of
              files over a reasonably fast network connection.

              gsutil performs the specified operation using a combination of
              multi-threading and multi-processing, using a number of threads
              and processors determined by the parallel_thread_count and
              parallel_process_count values set in the boto configuration
              file. You might want to experiment with these values, as the
              best values can vary based on a number of factors, including
              network speed, number of CPUs, and available memory.

              Using the -m option may make your performance worse if you
              are using a slower network, such as the typical network speeds
              offered by non-business home network plans. It can also make
              your performance worse for cases that perform all operations
              locally (e.g., gsutil rsync, where both source and destination
              URLs are on the local disk), because it can "thrash" your local
              disk.

              If a download or upload operation using parallel transfer fails
              before the entire transfer is complete (e.g. failing after 300 of
              1000 files have been transferred), you will need to restart the
              entire transfer.

              Also, although most commands will normally fail upon encountering
              an error when the -m flag is disabled, all commands will
              continue to try all operations when -m is enabled with multiple
              threads or processes, and the number of failed operations (if any)
              will be reported as an exception at the end of the command's
              execution.
```

Notes: at the time of this writing python3.8 seems to lead to problems with the `-m` flag. Use python3.7. More info on this [Github Issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/961)

Comment: Shall we want to copy files from gs buckets in a way that is shown below, gsutil cp -r gs://ukbb-exome-public/300k/results/results.mt ./

gsutil cp -r gs://ukbb-exome-public/300k/results/variant_results.mt ./        is there a way to enable parallelism ?

Answer (score 0):

For people not wanting to install the whole SDK and use Docker instead, here is the series of commands i used to download a Bucket to a Docker volume named googledata.
(Replace gs://assets with the name of your Bucket)

```
docker pull google/cloud-sdk:latest
docker run -ti --name gcloud-config google/cloud-sdk gcloud auth login
docker run --rm -ti -v googledata:/tmp --volumes-from gcloud-config google/cloud-sdk gsutil cp -r gs://assets /tmp
```

Docker Container see [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/).

Quite some effort just to get your data...